# SQL, Unable to resolve the error. The error is not a single single group function

Tags: sql, oracle

Error: ORA-00937, Not a single single group function.

Context: Find the number of unreserved seats on FBN001(RouteNo) on 20/06/2021(DateOfFlight).

This is the code that I have written, the logic of the code seems okay to me so I am unsure on how to proceed. From my understanding, the context only wants to find the number of unreserved seats so there should only be one attribute which is Available Seats. Thank you so much in advance to those that help me.

FYI: The data type for ReservationNo is Number(4) and the data type for Capacity is Number(3).

```
    SELECT (Capacity - COUNT(ReservationNo)) AS "Available Seat"
    FROM AIRPLANE A, FLIGHT F, RECORD R
    WHERE R.FlightNo = F.FlightNo
    AND F.SerialNo = A.SerialNo
    AND RouteNo = 'FBN001' 
    AND DateOfFlight = '20/06/2021';
```

Comment: Please show us some example data and desired result from that data because the error is simple : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b364939893274b8b5dc22c59a0afde9a

Comment: Oh I just click on the link, so in order to rectify the problem, all I need to do is just to add a GROUP BY Capacity;?

Comment: Or you can use MAX(Capacity) like shown on my link. You have two ways to resolve it on that link. Depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Aggregation function on the other column Capacity as well.

For your scenario you can try like below

```
SELECT (MAX(Capacity) - COUNT(ReservationNo)) AS "Available Seat"
   FROM AIRPLANE A, FLIGHT F, RECORD R
   WHERE R.FlightNo = F.FlightNo
   AND F.SerialNo = A.SerialNo
   AND RouteNo = 'FBN001' 
   AND DateOfFlight = '20/06/2021';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ReservationNo` is in the `Record` table then you can aggregate only that table rather than trying to aggregate the `JOIN` of all three tables:

```sql
SELECT A.Capacity - R.num_reservations AS "Available Seat"
FROM   FLIGHT F
       INNER JOIN AIRPLANE A
       ON (F.SerialNo = A.SerialNo)
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT flightno,
                COUNT(ReservationNo) AS num_reservations
         FROM   RECORD
         GROUP BY flightno
       ) R
       ON (R.FlightNo = F.FlightNo)
WHERE  F.RouteNo = 'FBN001' 
AND    F.DateOfFlight = DATE '2021-06-20';
```

Also:

- Use the ANSI join syntax rather than 20+ year-old proprietary Oracle comma-join syntax; and
- `'20/06/2021'` is a string literal that looks like a date but is not a `DATE` data type. Oracle will try to be helpful and perform an implicit string-to-date conversion using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter but this will fail if the session parameter does not match the format of your string; it is better practice to use either a date literal `DATE '2021-06-02'` or to use `TO_DATE` to perform an explicit conversion.